# String Array Split

Tags: java, string, join, methods

```
String s = "HELLO Java, JAVA IS INDEPENDENT. jAvA";
```

Here we can change all word JAVA to upper case by splitting it.

```
    String[] s2 = s.split(" ");

    for (String v : s2) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

Again how do we join them after correcting the case?

Comment: String concatenation, e.g., use the `+` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a regex, like this:

```
String x = s.replaceAll("[j|J][a|A][v|V][a|A]", "JAVA");
```

That's easier than using the split, especially since one of your Strings would have a comma in it (i.e. "Java,").

Comment: You can just use `String x = s.replaceAll("(?i:java)", "JAVA");`; thats much shorter.

Comment: Even better! Thanks. I'm not a regex expert. I just know enough to be dangerous. :)

Comment: And I am not sure the OP's intention ... but for the example given `String x = s.toUpperCase();` would also just work ...

Comment: that's ok, you got the right answer, just tuned it a little.

Comment: Yeah, and s.toUpperCase() would work in this case. But if you have the word "java" (in any case) embedded between other text, you'd have to be more creative. So regex is cleanest, IMO.

Comment: No - misunderstood me - I mean this would work: `System.out.println("HELLO Java, JAVA IS INDEPENDENT. jAvA".toUpperCase());`, becasue it's only the word 'java' in all sorts of mixed case. We cannot assume that it is, nor that it is not the case. The example given is just dubious.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the string back together like so:

```
String finalStringWeNeed = "";
for(String v : s2) {
    finalStringWeNeed = finalStringWeNeed + v + " ";
}
```

Comment: Luckily java will optimize that by using a StringBuilder internally. This is probably the most exact answer to what the OP was asking ("how do we join them"). However, the solution with the regex `replaceAll` is probably the best approach to solve the overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
     String s = "HELLO Java, JAVA IS INDEPENDENT. jAvA";         
     Pattern p=Pattern.compile("java.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     String[] s2=s.split("\\s");
      s="";
     for (String v : s2) {
         Matcher m=p.matcher(v);             
         if(m.matches()==true){
             v=v.toUpperCase();
             s=s+" "+v; 
         }
         else
            s=s+" "+v;                      
     }
     System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Your solution won't work. One of the tokens would be "Java," (notice the comma). So the v.equalsIgnoreCase("java") check would not evaluate to true in that case.